# Горизонтальная прокрутка широких таблиц в Android WebView

Tags: android, прокрутка, webview

Есть приложение **Андроид** с **WebView** во весь экран и с загружаемым в него HTML-кодом. Когда в коде попадаются широкие таблицы (HTML-тег **table**), не умещающиеся по ширине на экране, то они просто обрезаются без сроллинга. И эти таблицы невозможно просмотреть полностью. Горизонтальный скроллинг на таких страницах отсутствует, как и на всех остальных.

Как в **WebView** включить горизонтальный скроллинг для страниц с такими таблицами?

**WebView** использую самый простой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

Активити сейчас выглядит вот так:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()

        binding.webView.apply {
            with(settings) {
                this.javaScriptEnabled = true
                this.builtInZoomControls = true
                this.displayZoomControls = false
                this.useWideViewPort = true
            }

            isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = true
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            binding.webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        binding.webView.saveState(outState)
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        binding.webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && binding.webView.canGoBack()) {
            binding.webView.goBack()
            return true
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
    }

    private inner class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            view: WebView?,
            request: WebResourceRequest?
        ): Boolean {
            if (Uri.parse(request?.url.toString()).host
                == Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/index.html").host
            ) {
                return false
            }
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(request?.url.toString())).apply {
                startActivity(this)
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Страница на устройстве вот так:

[image: Страница на устройстве]

Не скроллируется вправо-влево. Таблица справа какбы обрезана, её нельзя сдвинуть и увидеть её правую часть.

Можно зумом увеличить масштаб страницы, тогда появится горизонтальный скролл. Но сдвинуть его можно толоько до обрезанного изначально края. И не больше.

Answer (score 0):

Можно программно включить:

```
webView.apply {
with(settings){
    this.javaScriptEnabled = true
    this.builtInZoomControls = true
    this.displayZoomControls = false
    this.useWideViewPort = true
}


isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = true
}
```

в вашем случае более важным есть:

```
this.useWideViewPort = true
```

update:
вот что у меня показывает при данном решении:

[картинка_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqmsb.png)

[картинка_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fNVV.png)

[картинка_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmMui.png)

Comment: Добавил в описание вопроса код активити. Сейчас на страницах появился зум. Можно только увеличивать. Потом обратно уменшать до изначального размера, в котором контент обрезан. Скроллится только после увеличения до обрезанного края и не дальше.

Comment: есть пример страницы которую можно потыкать?

Comment: Вот здесь лежит: https://github.com/DroidDump/OraclePLSQL/blob/master/app/src/main/assets/find-users-logged-into-oracle-plsql.html

Comment: @AlekseyVoko, прикрепил в ответ картинку, проверил в браузере, с виду все помещается, уточните пожалуйста - это то что нужно или нет по визуальным признакам?

Comment: Без CSS стили не подключились... Но на этой картинке видна только часть таблицы. Она скроллируется на устройстве вправо-влево? Нужен именно горизонтальный скролл.

Comment: Добавил скриншот, как выглядит на моих устройствах. И на устройствах, и в эмуляторах так же.

Comment: на той стр что я показал таблица показана полностью, то есть от края до края, оно уместилось нормально. я с браузерным отображением сравнил, поэтому и возник вопрос

Comment: Просто на вашем скриншоте видно только одну из колонок таблицы. И совсем не видно, можно ли страницу скроллировать вправо-влево по экрану.

Comment: страница не скролится горизонтально, но это и не нужно, так как вся информация уместилась нормально

Comment: На вашем скриншоте явно видно, что отображена толкьо одна из колонок таблицы. Правая колонка. С заголовком "Описание". Слева от этой колонки ещё должна находитсья колонка с заголовком "Столбец". Посмотрите, как эти же колонки с этими же заголовками отображены на моём скриншоте.

Comment: @AlekseyVoko, обновил ответ, три скриншота добавил

Comment: Обнаружил причину в CSS-файле, подключаемом к этим HTML. Параметр "#main {overflow: hidden;}". Поменял его на "auto". "useWideViewPort" не понадобился.